# Send Data to SQL via button when the data is not in the same form

Tags: javascript

I am making a family game we can play online, each player inputs an answer into an `input="text"` field and then clicks submit.

When I refresh my page all the answers are now shown on the page next to their name and I then click a button to check for duplicates. All those without duplicate answers get a point which is shown again next to their name.

I have written the code in PHP to get the words and the scores from an SQL database, but the problem I now have is that when I check for duplicates and update the scores on the page, they are only updates client side, so when I refresh the page next time to show the new answers, all scores revert back to the scores on the server.

I have made an update button which I want to click and it will send scores to the SQL DB. as follows,

- player enters answer on their computer and presses submit.
- I refresh the page on my computer (using over zoom and sharing screen for all to see)
- I then check the answers via button click which will check for duplicates and add 1 to the score of the
  user if they have a unique answer.
- I then click update which should send the new `score` value to the DB so next time I refresh my page it
  will show their updated score.

I am trying to do this as simply as possible for now.

I did the write the code to update the score but then I realised that the button I was using to update the score is in a different form than the scores input so when I click it, it cannot get any values.

An example of the html for the form which holds the players word and score is,

```
<form action="/scat/insertKaty.php" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="mx-3 names col-lg-3">
                <div id="katyName">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Katy">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mx-3 names col-lg-3">
                    <input type="text" name="katyWord" id="katyWord" value=<?php echo($katyWord)?>>
                </div>
            <div class="mx-3 names col-lg-3">
                <input type="number" id="katyScore" name="katyScore" value=<?php echo($katyScore)?>>
            </div>
            <div class="btn col-lg-1">
            <input type="submit" name="katyEnter" id="katyEnter">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

This line `<input type="number" id="katyScore" name="katyScore" value=<?php echo($katyScore)?>>` get ths score value for katy from the DB and inserts it into this input. WHen I check the words this value is increased by 1 if the answer is unique, but I need to somehow update it in the sql table when I click the  `update` button. The button so far looks like this,

```
      <form action="/scat/updateScore.php" method="post">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary " id="updateScore" name="updateScore" value="Update 
          Score" />
      </form>
```

I was thinking along the lines of adding a `<input type="hidden">` field for all 9 players which would hold the value of their current score on the client side, then pass this in the post method to the PHP script. But I am not sure how I can set the hidden input value to that of this line `<input type="number" id="katyScore" name="katyScore" value=<?php echo($katyScore)?>>` after I have run the check function, which updates the score.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the updatescore.php file , insert codes for returning the score to the HTML page.
Or you can use session function to hold the data in client side

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How To Answer Well](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)